# Code is not getting to starting point of try block when i make any change and save in debug mode in Eclipse java project

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Code is not getting to starting point of try block when i make any change and save in debug mode in Eclipse java project

```
try{
line 1;
line 2;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Code;
}
```

When I place a break point in line 2 and add a line 3 above line 2 , normally the control will go to the starting of try block that is line 1 and execute.
In my new eclipse , this is not happening .
Do I need to do any settings change to achieve this ?

I tried to get answers through search , but was unable to get this point 
I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers , Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)

Comment: Do you have automatic builds enabled?

Comment: Yes . Build Automatically is checked.

Comment: Hot swap enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after eclipse restart after enabling `Build Automatically`.